# This June - position within a sentence

Tags: subcontinental-english

> India rejected an Australian request to join maritime exercises along with the U.S. and Japan **this June**, and Navy Chief Admiral Sunil Lanba said **quite plainly** last month that there was no plan to “militarise” the Quad.

I took this line from a newspaper. 
I think the usage of "**this June**" may be incorrect. It should have been used before the conjunction "**along with**".
Also, the usage of the adverb "**quite**" is unnecessary.
can anyone please explain?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the quoted material. It's perfectly grammatical and idiomatic English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think either way is perfectly valid<sup>**1**</sup>. The possible disadvantage of:

> India rejected an Australian request to join maritime exercises *this June* along with the U.S. and Japan, ...

is that the thrust of the sentence seems to be about the participants of the exercises. Putting *this June* where you suggest tends to break that up; the original deals with all the participants (actual and requested) *before* mentioning when the exercises take place.

As for "*quite plainly*": this is simply a slightly more emphatic version of "*plainly*". Whether the "quite" is "necessary" or not depends on how strongly the speaker wanted to emphasise their point.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> The assumption for both versions is that *the exercises* were to take place in June: if the *request* had been made in June (for exercises at a later date), it should probably read:

> India rejected an Australian request *this June* to join...

And, as [FumbleFingers](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2637/fumblefingers) noted in a comment, if the *refusal* had been made in June (following a request made earlier) it should probably read:

> *This June* India rejected an Australian request to join...

Comment: And if the *refusal* had been made in June (after a request at an earlier date), it would probably be ***This June** India rejected an Australian request to join...*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thanks. I'll add that to my footnote.